# HTML Canvas "Commit" takes half of the render-time

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, 2d, game-development

i made a relatively heavy 2D game, rendering quiet a few sprites.
The problem: Half of the render-time is consumed by something where i cannot find any infos to.

Its called "Canvas2DLayerBridge::flushRecording" inside "LayerTreeHost::DoUpdateLayers".

The real game-render consumes around 5ms per frame, the flusRecording stuff takes around 2ms per frame (But twice: so around 4ms).

I was not able to find anything in google. Do you have any ideas, what this could be? And some solutions or "best-practises" to minimize the "flushRecording" time?

Thank you in advance.

[image: "Canvas2DLayerBridge::flushRecording" Taking up a lot of render-time]

Comment: I have never seen `Canvas2DLayerBridge` in any performance recordings on a wide range of PC's. I suggest you have a look through https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ where you might find somethinng to help diagnose the long GPU commit

Comment: Are you using multiple canvas elements on the page?
The best performance will be if no canvas elements are actually in the html.
They should be generated by javscript,
and put just the one final render canvas on the dom.
Ultimately only one canvas should get attached to the dom and copied to from
any other not displayed canvas's being used for layer work.

Comment: @mrall I did what you said. I now draw all images on internal canvases and when everything is done i draw the internal canvases onto the main canvas on the dom.
It seems to have just moved the problem. Now the "flushRecording" is not under "Commit" but just randomly at the end. 
I also tried changing the internal canvases to "OffscreenCanvas", it does pretty much the same thing but just with "finalizeFrame" at the end and not anymore "flushRecording"

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @cryofgaming How are you rendering sprites? Are you loading files individually or blitting from one sprite sheet? Blitting will give the best performance. Depending on what you are doing it could just be you've reached a limitation of the canvas element rendering as of now.

Comment: Commit, or compositor commit is a step in Chrome's rendering pipeline. More info here: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/blinkng/